# 'ng-waveform' is not a known element in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, waveform, angular-module

I was trying to use ng-waveform

> Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-waveform

In `app.module` file added

```
import { NgWaveformModule } from 'ng-waveform';
```

in import section

```
imports: [  
    NgWaveformModule,
  ],
```

in my `ts file` included

```
import { ITimeUpdateEvent, NgWaveformComponent, IRegionPositions } from 'ng-waveform';

export class WaveComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('waveform', { static: false }) waveform: NgWaveformComponent;
```

`html Component` added

```
 <ng-waveform #waveform class="waveform"
                                                [src]="src"
                                                [height]="150"
                                                [useRegion]="true"
                                                backgroundColor="#d3d3d3"
                                                regionBackgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
                                                regionStartStickColor="#21f032"
                                                regionEndStickColor="red"
                                                regionTextColor="#09417e"
                                                [withRegionLabels]="true"
                                                waveColor="#ff11ff"
                                                (trackLoaded)="onTrackLoaded($event)"
                                                (rendered)="onTrackRendered($event)"
                                                (durationChange)="onDurationChange($event)"
                                                (timeUpdate)="onTimeUpdate($event)"
                                                (paused)="onPaused()"
                                                (regionChange)="onRegionChange($event)"
                                              >
```

but still getting

> 'ng-waveform' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ng-waveform' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ng-waveform' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

Any solution to resolve this issue Thanks

Comment: Is the `WaveComponent` component,  present in the declaration part of your`ngModule` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think that's the issue Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add your `WaveComponent` in your module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgWaveformModule],
  declarations: [
   ....
   WaveComponent // don't forget to declare your components 
 ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```